# ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘multiset’ with no type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, ns-3

I am getting this error while building a software (ns3) using waf

```
In file included from ../src/internet-stack/mp-tcp-typedefs.cc:6:
../src/internet-stack/mp-tcp-typedefs.h:151: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘multiset’ with no type
../src/internet-stack/mp-tcp-typedefs.h:151: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
In file included from ../src/internet-stack/mp-tcp-socket-impl.cc:17:
../src/internet-stack/mp-tcp-typedefs.h:151: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘multiset’ with no type
../src/internet-stack/mp-tcp-typedefs.h:151: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
```

I searched for the error and the solutions say that probably I am missing a `using namespace std` or `#include <set>` in my C++ code, but my code is not missing those. The file where the error originates `[mp-tcp-typedefs.h]` is [here](http://codepad.org/AMed7bPw) (Line 151 has the error).

I tried resolving the error but still, I Am getting those for a long time now.

My gcc/g++ version is g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.7-8ubuntu1) 4.4.7.

Comment: Make sure that your .h file is what has `#include <set>`.

Comment: @Daniel yes, the .h file is the one I posted, it has #include <set>.

Comment: That's the flaw in linking to your code.  you should include the relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: Please try to use `std::multiset` to make sure this isn't a weird form of a name lookup issue. If you can, please try another compiler. The one you're currently using seems to run into some kind of syntax misinterpretation (probably caused by a problem in your source code **before** line 151). Another compiler might have better diagnostics.

Comment: @dyp I tried using that, no benefit. Again errors get thrown + new errors.

Comment: @Daniel The code was perhaps too big so I linked.

Comment: If the errors are different, this might help! Please show them, if they're different.

Comment: @dyp sorry, I checked again, the errors are actually the same.

Comment: @dyp I have g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.7-8ubuntu1) 4.4.7 version. Maybe this could be of any help ?

Comment: @Fernando: That's a *really* old version.  Look to see if your package manager has an update available to gcc 4.9.x

Comment: The issue is not caused by the code you've shown/linked: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/bj0SKMgUoHoIKrP8 So it must be caused by the headers, or by the the combination of the headers.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, I understand, I am using code that requires that version, I had to specifically install that older version (with a lot of pain). I am using an implementation of 2011 (of a protocol) and there s no other implementation available.

Comment: What kind of errors did you get when you tried with the latest compiler?  Usually fixing the broken code is a better idea than excising the new language features from the good code.

Comment: Try just using Clang and see what errors it gives; they're usually slightly better than GCC.

Comment: This is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887223/iso-c-forbids-declaration-of-multiset

Comment: The compiler isn't recognizing `multiset` as a type. While I'd expect another error or warning to be given (have you tried warn all?), it's possible one of the "ns3" headers is breaking STD's `multiset` in some unpredictable way. You could try moving the set include to after those and see if anything changes, and try `-Wall`. If a multiset were declared inside the `ns3` namespace in one of those, its scope would take precedence to the STD multiset. `-Wall` would give you this (as a shadowing warning).

Comment: @WilliamKappler I tried it , same errors.

Comment: This question is currently being discussed on Meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302538/2415822

Answer (score 1):

You should not put `using namespace std;` in a header file:

[Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

You can probably fix your code by *moving* your `using namespace std;` inside your own namespace changing this:

```
using namespace std;

namespace ns3 {
```

to this:

```
namespace ns3 {

using namespace std;
```

But better to remove the `using namespace std;` and qualify all your standard symbols with `std::` or else declare them individually *inside* your own namespace.

```
namespace ns3 {

using std::string;
using std::list;
using std::multiset;
using std::queue;
```

Comment: Could you kindly suggest some readings so that I could try fixing the error ?

Comment: @Fernando When I made these changes it fixed your error on my system. Perhaps you didn't get it right? Can you post your new code somewhere so I can take a look?

Comment: @Fernando There is no siubstitute for a good book. Here is a *recommended* list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: yes thanks for the guidance but really is this some kind  of esosteric error ? It's just a syntax error like, it can't compile, what could be so wrong ?

Comment: @Fernando Just put `std::` in front of your declation on line `151` so its like this: `std::multiset<double> measuredRTT;`. Do that for each of the *standard* containers you use.

Comment: thanks again but STill I get the same errors on the same line.

Comment: **Stop!** Alter your question so that it presents a [complete, minimal testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Galik with std:: i get an extra error error: invalid use of ‘::’

Comment: @Fernando Can you post your code somewhere so I can see what you did?